# how to resolve 500 internal server error for my php application?

Tags: php, apache, joomla2.5, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I am getting 500 internal server error as mentioned below but i have the mentioned file located at /var/www/html/mywebsite/new_catalogue_request.php

```
Request URL: https://www.mywebsite.com/custom_vm/new_catalogue_request.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Below are the tools details:

1. PHP Version- 5.3
2. Joomla Version- 2.5
3. Apache- 2.4

Efforts:

1. I Checked the apache and other possible error logs but dint get much info.
2. Tried executing the command "chmod -R 755 /mywebsite" but dint help much.

Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: perhaps you might add the `new_catalogue_request.php` file / code to the question?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: `PHP 5.3` I think its also time to update, maybe you are using a plugin that use newer functions that are not working in your version, but only the logs can tell